# Pet Bearded Dragon Attacks when outdoors

Tags: behavior, bearded-dragon

I've read in many places that is OK to take your pet beardie out in the garden, provided it's a place safe from predators, to sit a bit in the natural sunlight.

Well, my beardie, otherwise very friendly, as soon as I put him in the garden and give him 2 minutes - he starts running around frantically and if you get close, it puffs and attacks you. I mean like, literally runs to bite you. I had to cover him with a thick blanket and take him back inside, where he calmed down.

I feel really guilty now for buying one. It just feels like he will always be a wild animal and putting him in an enclosure and breed him to become a pet is just wrong. He was so desperately looking to run and be free. I couldn't wait for the good weather to come to be able to let him out in the garden and now I am just really disappointed. Anyone else having this problem with their beardie?

Answer (score 1):

He is probably just scared, be it because of a bird or just a shadow. Going from the safety of a vivarium to outside is a scary thing for them, considering how easily they can be prey. See this link about their "third eye": http://www.anapsid.org/parietal.html
Taking him outside more regularly may get him more used to it. Also, when outside, perhaps put him in a cage that you can cover the top of while he gets used to the surroundings, and slowly remove the cover every time you take him outside.